# Identificar via Windows Forms C# a URL que o usuário acessa

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma LAN House e gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa com gráficos sobre os sites que meus clientes acessam.

Para isso, preciso de uma maneira de capturar as URL's que eles digitam no browser por meio de uma aplicação Windows Forms em C#, alguém já fez essa solução ou tem ideia de como realizá-la?

Preciso apenas da função que captura as URL's.

Answer (score 2):

Para esta tarefa eu não usaria um aplicativo simples, porque:

- Fica dependendo do software navegador, vai ter que acessar um recurso interno dele: a caixa de edição. E como se já não fosse suficientemente difícil, uma atualização pode mudar o acesso ao recurso e o software deixará de funcionar;
- Nem todo o acesso é digitado, pode ser de interesse endereços clicados ou que sejam digitados diretamente na linha de comando caso seja possível, ou então com atalhos;
- Caso todos os acesso sejam capturados, ainda depende de conseguir acessar recursos do navegador;
- Análise de todo o tráfego de rede evita acessar o navegador, mas ficaria, um pouquinho absurdamente complexo.
- O software tem que ser instalado em todas as máquinas que acessam a internet, mesmo com os dados centralizados em um servidor.

Talvez fosse mais fácil criar um aplicativo com um componente de navegação de internet, que é possível, mas vai envolver fazer toda a interface com o cliente, pois o componente de navegação é só o quadro que acessa a internet. Mas ainda deve ser complexo, embora seja uma alternativa válida. Este software poderia gravar ou enviar a lista de páginas acessadas a um banco de dados central.

Eu usaria um proxy transparente em um computador separado ou mesmo em uma máquina virtual, pois pode gravar um log com todos os endereços de acessos. Transparente pois descarta a necessidade de configurar os clientes.

Só não espere que o log seja fácil de ler, pois deverá conter uma grande quantidade de registros e informações. Existem interfaces web que ajudam a analisar os logs.

O novo servidor proxy seria o gateway e só é necessário configurar o DHCP, supondo as estações se configurem com ele atualmente.

E, se tratando de uma lanhouse, existem outras vantagens:

- Devem existir várias estações, nenhuma delas precisará ser modificada;
- Pode fazer uma parte da segurança, pois, se desejável, permite configurar filtros para endereços ou conteúdos proibidos;
- Já que se trata de uma máquina com OS e tudo, pode melhorar mais a segurança com a adição de um firewall;
- Pode melhorar a velocidade de navegação, pela utilização de cache. Se o conteúdo for estático, por exemplo uma imagem, sua internet só é utilizada no primeiro acesso, depois disso, qualquer usuário que precise a mesma imagem a obterá do cache;
- Pode melhorar mais a velocidade de navegação se utilizar o cache em um ramdrive, porém neste caso o cache se perde ao desligar, e é bom ter uma quantidade de RAM razoável.

E, por fim, será mais fácil instalar e configurar um servidor proxy novo que criar um aplicativo (em C#) para capturar um recurso string de um software de terceiros (navegador) ou capturar e analisar o tráfego de rede ou então criar um aplicativo que faça o papel de navegador.

O OS poderia ser GNU/Linux, FreeBSD ou outro que agrade e tenha disponível software para criar um servidor proxy e possivelmente firewall. Não me recordo de proxy, mas para firewall já usei um sistema que cabia em um disquete de 3,5".

Não esquecer de ter em algum lugar acessível aos clientes, contrato, quadro de informações, etc, o aviso de que todos os acessos são monitorados e registrados, e o conteúdo estático (que não muda e não tem segurança) pode ficar gravado em cache!